# access request object in custom function without passing as arg - django

Tags: django, logging

Django issue: I’ve an issue accessing request object of api in a custom logger function where I save my logs to -> rabbitMQ and then Elastic for analysis. I need some of the information from request object and a userInfo(I add that key into request object at auth middleware), now when I create log schema I need some of the fields like request body, path , method, user info etc. to create user-specific logs. But I can’t pass request object directly to each function wherever I’m using my logger. Worst case: view -> function1 -> function2 -> function3…and so on. I need to pass request object to this nested chain where I’m logging in function_n. Is there any other way than passing request all through the chain. Any luck?

Log Schema: <there have been multiple logs in a single api request at any point and of any type <info, error, warn or critical>

```
{
"tags": "LOG_TYPE_SHORTHAND",
"custom": true,
"req_id": "user_id:req_start_time", // nano seconds
"timestamp": "TIMESTAMP", // for debugging and visual representations
"message": "LOG_MESSAGE", // actual msg for that particular log
"level": "LOG_LEVEL", // info, warn, err, debug, critical
"service": "SERVICE_NAME", // router/main OR search - configurable once at api server initialization
"module": "MODULE_NAME",
"function": "FUNCTION_NAME", 
"traceback": "TRACEBACK_DETAILS", // in case of err tracing,
"request": { // when debugging Is on
"method": "REQUEST_METHOD",
"path": "REQUEST_PATH",
"query_params": "QUERY_PARAMETERS_ONLY_IF_NEEDED",
"body": "REQUEST_BODY_ONLY_IF_NEEDED"
},
"response": { // when debugging Is on
"status": "RESPONSE_STATUS",
"body": "RESPONSE_BODY",
"duration": "RESPONSE_TIME"
},
"user": {
"id": "USER_ID",
"mobile": "USER_MOBILE",
},
"extra_data": {} 
}) 

Wsgi’s get_current_request is deprecated and context processors only serve request object in templates.
```